# How to make Web service "page" which can be data source for Ms Office Excel 2007

Tags: web-services, excel, office-interop, office-2007

In MS-Excel under the Data tab there is button "From WEB".
Ill love to try make my web-service (web-page ) which can supply data for  Sheet.
Where I should start looking and what kind of web service, page EXCEL can import using this method.
Ill love to try make this using C# (.NET) ASP.NET

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "From Web" button pulls information from any HTML table.

You just have to put the data in an HTML table, and Excel will pull that data into a new spreadsheet or an existing spreadsheet.